# mmenu js word-press plugin external hamburger not working

Tags: javascript, mmenu

Using the WordPress paid plugin though and I am trying to create an external button that can close the menu.

On full screen the MMENU is open, but the button when clicked does not collapse unless the screen resolution passes the breakpoint. After this the menu collapses and the button starts working....

Breakpoint is set to: 768px.

Here is the code I am using for the button:

```
<a id="hamburger" href="#my-menu" class="hamburger is-active">
<i class="fas fa-bars"></I>
</a>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the `css` file or any `javascript` files in relation for 768px?

Comment: no haven't looked. this is a custom theme, so there is no JS from my end. I have not looked into the WP plugin js itself, but this might not be ideal to change...